# PIC C compiler RS232 transmittion code

Tags: c, pic

I wanna ask about how to write a code in PIC C compiler for PIC18f4620 to transmite a date when one of the analoge inputs is 1

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And you should be more specific when you say "when one of the analoge inputs is 1".

Answer (score 0):

That is really too broad a question for this site.  How you write the code depends on which PIC C compiler you have and what they have in their drivers library.   Higher end PIC C compilers provide have UART driver code you can include in your program that makes it pretty easy.

As far as the technique to use, you should Google around and also scour the Microchip website for UART programming tutorials for PIC.

You don't need to be *that* specific about the PIC chip family, because the C code you write is the same for the 18F family, 17F, 16F, etc...  With PIC chips the UART works pretty much the same only the internal register addresses change, so you just have to set the device type for your code and the C compiler.

You just need to do some basic research and you'll figure it out. CCS and other compiler vendors have [forums](http://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=173498) where you can ask PIC C related questions and find guidelines.

Comment: You're welcome. If that answer helps you, please click the √ to the left of the answer.